# Delete multiple items array without disrupt order of the key PHP

Tags: php, arrays, key

I want to delete multiple items array without disrupt order the key. So what is the best way to do that problem? because i tried use splice but the key is skipped for deleted element

the example :

```
$del_item = array('orange', blueberry);
$array = array('apple', 'orange', 'strawberry', 'blueberry', 'kiwi');
print_r($array);
//[0]=>"apple", [1]=>"orange", [2]=>"strawberry", [3]=>"blueberry", [4]=>"kiwi"

$deleted= array('apple', 'strawberry', 'kiwi');
print_r($deleted);
//[0]=>"apple", [1]=>"strawberry", [2]=>"kiwi"
```

Comment: *because i tried use splice but the key is skipped for deleted element* - you want the keys remain there with blank values?

Comment: You have not deleted anything you create two arrays and obviously they look different. If you unset (delete) an item then you will get the result you are looking for

Comment: @SougataBose i want the order key remain 0 1 2 3 4 5 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_diff` with `array_values` as

```
$deleted = array_values(array_diff($array, $del_item));
```

The `array_diff` will delete the item you want and the `array_values` will reindex them

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate the array, [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2a7a0620bb74307fc3ac3373bdc770f237e69105)

```
$del_item = array('orange', 'blueberry');
$array = array('apple', 'orange', 'strawberry', 'blueberry', 'kiwi');
$del_item = array_flip($del_item);
$result = [];
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    if(!isset($del_item[$value])){
        $result[$key] = $value;
    }
}
print_r($result);
```